# Looping 2 variables in R

Tags: r

```
Results = rep(0,15)
number <- 1:500
for(i in 1:100) {
   Results[i] <- sum(sample(number, 20, replace = F))/20)}
```

I wish to change the sample size 20, 10, 15 in the same loop. How can do it in a single loop?

Comment: Why is there the range 1:100 while Results is having only 15 values? do you want to have individual columns in Results for each of the sample sizes or only one value out of these three sample sizes needs to be added to Results>

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Therefore, I will give only a hint instead of a code example. One approach could be a matrix or data frame with all combinations, then you can iterate over its rows with a single column with a loop, or with an apply function or with a tidyverse approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop within a loop.
Continuing what you started makes it difficult, because making sure the values go into the correct cell of your empty pre-structured dataframe requires some thinking. I would just start with a dataframe with 0 rows, and use rowbind to add the results of each itteration.

First create an empty data frame with 0 rows:

```
Results2 = data.frame(samplesize=c(), sum = c())
```

Set some parameters:

```
numbersToSampleFrom <- 1:500
samplesizes <- c(10, 20, 50)
NumberOfIterations <- 100
```

Loop it together

```
for(s in seq_along(samplesizes)){
  for(i in 1:NumberOfIterations) {

    Results2 <- rbind(Results2, data.frame(samplesize= samplesizes[s], 
                                           sum = sum(sample(number, samplesizes[s], replace = F))/samplesizes[s])
                      )

  }
}
```

For each iteration it picks a sample size, does the sampling and creates a dataframe with one row, that you then bind to the Results2 dataframe.

There will be lots of ways to do this, this one is an easy modification from your code (I think).